# the sum of entered number with old number in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have three fields and table in database called "Support"

```
Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/>
<br><br>
Serial:<input type="text" name="badge" id="badge" value=""/>
<br><br>
Quantity:<input type="text" name="address" id="address" value=""/>
<br><br>
```

if the name and Serial are exists in the database 
(The quantity field) it can be the sum of entered number with old number in the database.
for example, the quantity is 5 we insert the value 6
the quantity will be 5+6= 11.

how can i do that ?

Comment: Show us , what you've tried up to now

Comment: HTML form with `method="post"`, in PHP check for `$_POST` array. Use PDO to access database.

Comment: Query 1 check if exist. Query 2, if exist add value. Query 3 if not exist insert.

Comment: how to save in php, show here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple SQL query after you get the parameters from `$_POST`:

```
UPDATE Support SET Quantity = Quantity + ? WHERE Serial = ? AND Name = ?  # passing escaped parameters from the form
```

First parameter would be `$_POST['address']`, second `$_POST['badge']` and third `$_POST['name']`